# Why does this HTML5 Video Tag not work in Firefox 3.6 and why does it not autoplay in Safari?

Tags: firefox, video, html, tags

```
<video controls="" autoplay="" tabindex="0"><source type="video/mp4" src="pird2.mp4"></source></video>
```

Comment: Unsure, but try removing ="" for autoplay and controls. No need to assign a value, they just need to be there or not there.

Answer (score 1):

Re MP4 and Firefox: Firefox supports only Ogg in `Video` tags because the MP4 license was too expensive. See this [article](http://pauljacobson.org/2010/01/22/firefox-and-its-limited-html-5-video-support/).

Re autoplay: I'm not very familiar with HTML 5, but you don't seem to be setting the `autoplay` property, are you? It probably would have to be something like

```
autoplay="autoplay"
```

or simply

```
autoplay
```

to work.

Comment: first, it's not the cost.  The MP4 patents are not available under a GPL-compatible license at any price.  Second, latest Firefox also supports [WebM](http://www.webmproject.org/), an efficient new open standard codec released by Google.  Finally, autoplay is a boolean attribute, so it is true when it is present (even with empty value).

Comment: @Matthew re the license, cost is at least part of the issue: The Mozilla Foundation considered licensing the codec, but turned it down due to the multi-million dollar investment it would have been (and of course the license problems that part of the software would have brought with it, you're right in that). See weblogs.mozillazine.org/roc/archives/2010/01/… Great to know about WebM, looks interesting. Re the attribute: if boolean attributes work anything like in HTML 4, autoplay="" *will* turn it off.

Comment: how can i turn autoplay on? 

Which format should i use, that it works in iPad and Firefox

Comment: for [HTML 5](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#boolean-attribute), "The presence of a boolean attribute on an element represents the true value, and the absence of the attribute represents the false value.  If the attribute is present, its value must either be the empty string or a value that is an ASCII case-insensitive match for the attribute's canonical name."  So `autoplay=""` and `autoplay="autoplay"`  are both right.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a great site for HTML5 Video information: [Dive Into HTML5](http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/video.html)